# BIND to resolve servers in intranet and internet for the same domain

Tags: dns, bind, intranet, nameservers, zone

Is this at all possible if so how?
BIND to resolve servers in intranet and internet for the same domain

Scenario

zone is **example.com**

i have one server **server1.example.com** but it is located on a virtual private server on the cloud in the internet.

I have the domain **exmaple.com** bought at godaddy. hence the nameservers for example.com are of godaddy.

I have added a A record  in godaddy for **server1.example.com** to point to the public ip of the VPS.

Now at my home (intranet) i have setup a BIND DNS server having ip **10.10.10.100**.

And have added the zone **example.com** to it.

Have then added **A** record for **server22.example.com** and ipaddress being **10.10.10.10** in my BIND config.

Now from a laptop inside my home network, i am able to resolve **server1.example.com**; probably the global dns are resolving this address for me.

Laptop's DNS config is as below

DNS1: 10.10.10.100

DNS2: 4.2.2.2

DNS3: 8.8.8.8

However i am NOT able to resolve **server22.example.com** which is inside my intranet.

I Guess when i tried to resolve **server22.example.com**. DNS1:10.10.10.100 should have resolved it for me, since that is first in my list, and it knows what is the the ipaddress of **server22.example.com**

But unfortunately it is not. What is that i am doing wrong ?

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to put the names that need non-Internet resolution in /etc/hosts:

10.10.10.10 server22.example.com

(The file is usually C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS on Windows machines)

If you insist on having the DNS server do it, one solution is to have two BIND servers; one is for the internet at large and doesn't have the server22.example.com record.  The intranet private BIND server should start with the same zone file, but with the record for server22.example.com added to it.

Another option is to use "split horizon DNS" with BIND: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/#split-view

Comment: dns split horizon DNS nice feature!